# Need to fire kusto query on a table at runtime

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am working on a scenario where after specific time interval a **new table is being created**. I have one PowerBI report which runs on this kusto query. This kusto query should run on the **latest table** which was created. Since table name contains created date, **I can find the latest tablename with below query** , However how to take the out output of below query in a **single variable**? So that my **subsequent query** can pick this table name to generate the report.

**Query** :

.show tables
| where TableName contains "XXX"
| project TableName , year = split(TableName,"*")[3],month = split(TableName,"*")[4], day = split(TableName,"_")[5]
| project TableName , CreatedDate = todatetime(strcat(year,month,day))
| order by  CreatedDate | project TableName| take 1

Output: [single row single column]

Tablename => XXX_12_11_2020

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [table scope function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/tablefunction) you can use it in a function and refer to the function from PBI. See how to use admin commands in query [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/)